# How to expand a list in a pandas dataframe without repeating other column values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, expand

I was wondering how I would be able to expand out a list in a cell without repeating variables in other cells.

[image: Dataframe Before]

[image: Dataframe After]

The goal is to get it so that the list is expanded but the first column is not repeated. I know how to expand the list out but I would not like to have the first column values repeated if that is possible. Thank you for any help!!

Comment: Is the second photo your desired outcome or what you're stuck with? Also, are those the only two columns? Is this a Series or a DataFrame?

Comment: this is a dataframe, and I would like to expand whats in the first photo to the second. I am struggling figuring out how to expand a list out without repeating the first column values.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that question. With the explode method, the other columns will not remain blank, but instead repeat them with value that aligns with the list. I am looking to have the list expanded without the other variables in the other columns repeated.

Comment: Is it just for aesthetic purposes? Or do you want to ensure that records not beginning with 1 are not related to the records that do begin with 1?

Comment: Nope -- just for aesthetic purposes. I just want to be able to repeat the rows in the second column while having the rows in the first column not repeated.

Comment: In other words, is it your intended goal that, if we try to regroup the second column by the first, the groups would be: ```{'a': ['1 hey'], 'b':['1what'], '':['2 hi','3 hello','2 how','3 say']}```?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213960/discussion-between-frankmank1-and-ltheriault).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get what you're asking for, you still have to use `explode()` to get what you need. You just have to take it a step further and change the values of the first column. Please note that this will destroy the association between the elements of the list and the letter of the row they were first in. You would be creating a third value for the column (an empty string) that would be repeated for every record not beginning with 1.

If you want to eliminate the value from the rows you are talking about but still want to have those records associated with the value that their list was associated with, you can't. It's not logically possible for a value to both be in a given cell but also not be in that cell. So, I will show you the steps for eliminating the original association.

For this example, I named the columns since they are not provided.

```
data = [
    ["a",["1 hey","2 hi","3 hello"]],
    ["b",["1 what","2 how","3 say"]]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["first","second"])
df = df.explode("second")
df['first'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['first'] if x['second'][0] == '1' else '', axis=1)
```

Comment: Excellent answer,  thanks for taking the time to write this out.

Comment: Had a quick question, is there a way to change if `x['second'][0] == '1'` in the last line of the code to make it so that it will return ' ' if the value above x['first'] is the same?